# How to get the code parameter in and oAuth process with Slack in node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, slack

I'm trying to develop an app for slack.
I'm want to get the code parameter send in answer to the oauth flow with a slack button but I don't know how to get the parameter.

In fact I sent first the button then someone can click on it an implement the app on its slack channel then the oauth flow redirect me to a new webpage which url is 
*https://www.myappname.com/oauth/?code=[parameter I wan't to get]&state=*

The problem is that my method to get the code parameter doesn't wait for the redirection.

Here is my code :

```js
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use('/', router);

recupCode = function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.params);
        console.log('cb1 : le code est récupéré');
    res.end(); 
};

//Fonctions de Callback
boutonSlack = function(req, res) {
        res.send('<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=incoming-webhook,'
                                                                                                        +'&client_id='+process.env.CLIENT_ID+'">' 
                    +'<img alt="Add to Slack" height="40" width="139"'
                    +'src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" '
                    +'srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, '
                    +'https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x" /></a>');

        console.log('cb0:le bouton slack s\'affiche');
    router.get('/oauth/',recupCode);
};

router.get('/',boutonSlack);
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Ready');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you wanted to obtain the code - the access code is sent as a **url** parameter from Slack to your app in a GET request after the user clicks on your *Add to Slack* button and authorizes Slack's request to install your app. Your app waits for these requests from Slack in the `router.get('/', function(request, response){};`and you use **request.url** to access the string containing the code.

With some string manipulation you can extract the **code** value from the url and call Slack's `auth.access(client_id, client_secret, code)` in a request to exchange the code for your client's access_token. This access_token is what you use to do everything with a team, so you'll want to store it.

https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.access

The button is usually displayed on a website and the node application acts as a server waiting for authorization requests coming from Slack.

https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button

This is how I setup my index.js file in my node app to wait for installation requests. I don't use the router directly and I prefer the request library

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request'); //I prefer the request library to make requests 

var path_to_access_token = "https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=[INSERT_CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET]&code="; //Slack URL to call to receive accessToken
var app = express();

 /* WAIT FOR NEW APP INSTALLATION REQUESTS FROM SLACK */
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  // Tease out accessCode from the Slack request, if it exists 
  var url = req.url;
  var codePos = url.indexOf("code="); //index where code= starts in url
  var codeStartPos = codePos + 5; //Start of accessCode (+5 because code= is 5 characters)
  var endingPos = url.indexOf("&"); //End of accessCode, where another parameter starts
  var accessCode = url.substring(codeStartPos, endingPos).toString();   //Extract code from url

  // Verify user accepted Slack's auth request by looking for access_code existence
  if (codePos > -1) {    // User authorized oAuth request from Slack
    var completePath = path + accessCode; //Slack API call + code to receive accessToken and teamInfo
    request(completePath, function(error, response, body) { // Request token from Slack using the access_code, then handle response
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200 && teamInfo.ok == true){
        var teamInfo = JSON.parse(body);   //Slack sends back access_code and team info in a JSON object
        //SAVE THE ACCESS_CODE
      } else {
        //ERROR
      }
     });
   } else {          //User denied auth request from Slack, so reroute back to signup page to start over
    //REROUTE USER BACK TO INSTALL PAGE, THEY DENIED AUTH REQUEST
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you I've  change my script and know its working

Comment: You can get the access code from the request using [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).